# How to read the payload in applaunchwithoption in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate, payload, ios8.3

I have implemented remote push notification for my iOS app. and it has a custom payload. Like this one

```
 "aps": {
    "alert": "joetheman",
    "sound": "default"
},
"message": "Some custom message for your app",
"id": 1234
```

When click on the notification on the lock screen, according to the id I wanna load different screen of the app (when app is not running, If I got a notification and the id is 2, app should open with the BookingViewController opened). So how can I read the custom payload in my `applaunchwithOption` in `AppDelegate` and also in the `notificationdidreceived` delegate too.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can use Following Method to handel PUSH notification:---

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
    NSString *msg=[userInfo objectForKey:@"message"];
    //Application is Running
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){

        if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
        [self.nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        }
        else if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]isEqualToString:@"2"]) {                 
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
        [self.nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       }
   }
//when Application in Background
   else{
       if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
        [self.nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       }

       else if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"]isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
        [self.nav setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Then if the app is not runing in background and If user still got a notification under which delegate I should handle it. (user receive the notification before he open the app first time, in this case as I know applicationddidlaunchwithoption will fire how to do this under this delegate?)

Comment: Yes, you are right In that case you need to handel your app through applicationdidlaunchwithoption

Comment: how can I access my payload within the applicationdidlaunchwithoption?

Comment: applicationdidlaunch with option has launch option that is launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];